# Outlook Addin - New appointment Event Handler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook

I developed an Outlook Addin that intercept the creation of new appointment items using the `ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler` handler.

How can I detect if the new appointment is created by my local client or by a remote one (like web/mobile application)?

I need to intercept only the appointments created by my client (using the new appointment window or just typing on the calendar).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no trivial way to detect new items creation with the ItemAdd event handler only. Moreover, the Outlook object model doesn't provide such information out of the box.

You can handle the `NewInspector` event and check whether a new appointment item is created. For new items the `EntryID` property value is empty (`String.Empty`).

Also you may try to handle the `SelectionChange` event of the Explorer class where you may check the `Selection` object. If it also contains an item with an empty string for the `EntryID` property then it is a new one.

Thus, you will be able to distinguish items and get a definitive answer whether they were created by users or not.

Comment: The problem is that the NewInspector event is not fired when user write directly on the calendar to create a new appointment (without using the window).

Comment: Yes, that is for inspectors. But for explorer windows you need to handle the `SelectionChange` event of the `Explorer` class.

Comment: I also tried to check the SelectionChange event during the creation of new appointment (by typing on calendar) and the Selection object of the Explorer has always Count 0.

Comment: You may try to combine the `SelectionChange`, `ItemAdd` events and the `CreationTime` property which returns a date indicating the creation time for the Outlook item.

Comment: I tried but with no results :( I need to find a property of the item that says if it is a local one